# Make the panels go onto the new line when the resolution changes

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a few panels which work fine but when i resize the browser they don't look quite right, I want something like this:

```
|1|  |2|  |3|  |4|
|5|  |6|
```

Then when the browser resizes it should go

```
|1|  |2|  |3|
|4|  |5|  |6|
```

But with the current code it's doing this

```
|1|  |2|  |3|
          |4|
```

Here is my code:

```
<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><strong><a href="index.php?page=portfolio&work=driveways">Driveways</a></strong></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Blockpaving<br />
                Indian stone<br />
                Shingle<br />
                Concrete<br />
                Crossovers<br />
                Drainage<br />
                Drive Cleaning<br />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><strong><a href="index.php?page=portfolio&work=patios">Patios</a></strong></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Slabs<br />
                Indian stone<br />
                York stone<br />
                Brick surrounds<br />
                Drainage<br />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><strong><a href="index.php?page=portfolio&work=paths">Paths</a></strong></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Blockpaving<br />
                Slab<br />
                Indian stone<br />
                Concrete<br />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading"><strong><a href="index.php?page=portfolio&work=decking">Decking</a></strong></div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                Timber<br />
                Composite<br />
                Balustrades<br />
                Steps<br />
                Pergolas<br />
                Shed/Bar Conversions<br />
            </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add before 3 and 4 block div:

```
<div class="clearfix visible-md-block"></div>
```

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

Comment: And then it's going to break when the viewport gets so small, that there are only 1 element per line...

Comment: @Christoph True, in that case, do not display this div.

Comment: Thanks, i used this method it seems to have worked ok.

Comment: @Exoon this will break in other circumstances, like I mentioned before. If you have the time, I suggest you take a look at the flex box approach, which is more robust and really intended for these use cases.